# Prevent Facebook from fetching and suggesting a thumbnail image when sharing an article

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

If no `og:image` or `link rel=”image_src“` is given, Facebook tries to guess the thumbnail image for the article url by scraping the html for images.

Is there any way to prevent Facebook from doing this?

What I'm basically trying to achieve is to have my articles shared on Facebook without any images.

(I know it's a rather unusual question, but I definitely don't want to provide any `og:image` or `link rel=”image_src“` meta information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're asking for but have you considered specifying either one of those tags and providing a URL to a spacer image (1x1px with a transparent or white background)?